# How many operations to transform RPN string into valid RPN string?

Tags: python

I failed an interview earlier this morning on this question, and haven't been able to figure out why. Can anyone help me out?

An expression consisting of operands and binary operators can be written in Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) by writing both the operands followed by the operator. For example, 3 + (4 * 5) can be written as "3 4 5 * +".

You are given a string consisting of x's and *'s. x represents an operand and * represents a binary operator. It is easy to see that not all such strings represent valid RPN expressions. For example, the "x*x" is not a valid RPN expression, while "xx*" and "xxx**" are valid expressions. What is the minimum number of insert, delete and replace operations needed to convert the given string into a valid RPN expression?

```
5
x
xx*
xxx**
*xx
xx*xx**
```

OUTPUT

```
0
0
0
2
0
```

Code so far:

```
import fileinput

def solution (rpn):
    xs = 0
    numReplaces = 0
    numDeletes = 0
    numInserts = 0

    for i in xrange(len(rpn)):
        if rpn[i] == 'x':
            xs += 1
        elif rpn[i] == '*':
            if xs > 1:
                xs -= 1
            elif xs == 1:
                if numDeletes > 0:
                   numReplaces += 1
                   numDeletes -= 1
                else:
                    if i == len(rpn)-1:
                        numInserts += 1
                    else:
                        numDeletes += 1
            else:
                if numDeletes > 1:
                    numDeletes -= 2
                    numReplaces += 2
                else:
                    numDeletes += 1

    while xs > 1:
        if xs > 2:
            numReplaces += 1
            xs -= 2
        if xs == 2:
            numInserts += 1
            xs -= 1

    return numReplaces + numDeletes + numInserts

    first = True
    for line in fileinput.input():
        if first:
            numCases = int(line)
            first = False

        else:
            print solution(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to start is that RPM evaluation can be performed easily by maintaining a stack of operands. For a valid input string, when you hit an operator, you pop the last two values off the stack, apply the operator and push the result back on to the stack.

Therefore, we need to find the value added by each of the "fixes":

1. Insert

   - Operand: you hit an operator, and there is only one item on the stack
   - Operator: You finish the string and there are multiple items left on the stack
2. Delete

   - Operand: you are at the end of the string. Adding operators will have the same result
   - Operator: there is only one item on the stack, adding an operand will have the same result. If the stack is empty, delete the operator
3. Replace

   - Operator -> operand: There is only one operand on the stack
   - Operand -> operator: *Here be dragons.* I believe that this will be useful only when you're out of operators, meaning the stack size is > 1; unfortunately, we don't know if these are direct operands or the result of operations, so we'll just add `n-1` operators to condense the stack into a result.

I'm not 100% sure on these, but it sounds like any error condition can be handled by any of these, at equal cost, so:

```
def count_errors(input_):
    def tokenize(input_):
        ''' for our purposes, each character is a token '''
        for char in input_:
            yield char

    def is_operator(val):
        return val == '*'

    def is_operand(val):
        return val == 'x'

    stack = []
    error = 0
    for token in tokenize(input_):
        if is_operand(token):
            stack.append(token)
        elif is_operator(token):
            if len(stack) >= 2:
                stack.pop()
                stack.pop()
                stack.append('x')
            elif len(stack) == 1:
                stack.pop()
                stack.append('x')
                errors += 1
            else:
                errors += 1

    if len(stack):
        return errors + len(stack) - 1
    else:
        return errors + 1
```